# How to make a void method with Retrofit return string?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

So, here is the method in my adapter. Later on, in onBindViewHolder() method I want to perform such action: `String pic_url = showJustProduct(product_name);`, but the onResponse method can`t return anything except void. What should I do to put **img_url** to **pic_url**?

```
public void showJustProduct(String title){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://url")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JustJsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JustJsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<JustProducts> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getProducts(title);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JustProducts>() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<JustProducts> call, @NotNull Response<JustProducts> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    List<JustProduct> justproducts = response.body().getProducts();
                    JustProduct justProduct = justproducts.get(0);
                    String img_url = justProduct.getImage();
                    Log.e("1", "it works!");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<JustProducts> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                Log.e("failure", Objects.requireNonNull(t.getLocalizedMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use synchronized `call.execute()` method instead of `call.enqueue()`.

> This can lead to `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So be sure to execute it on background thread not UI thread.

Example:

```
Response<JustProducts> response = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getProducts(title).execute();
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    ...
}
```